# SQL Server : get count and sum of columns

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a website that people post text messages. users can rate the messages (1 to 5). I'm recording this ratings into a table to:

1. avoid multiple rating by one user for the same post
2. to be able get the average rating of a post.

but I also the number of votes are important too. for example a post having 10 votes of 3 (makes 30) are valuable than the post with 2 votes of 5 (that makes 10). Now when I'm showing a page with 20 of this messages I want to show their rating too

This is my rating table:

```
create table ratings(
[id] int primary key identity(1,1),
[msgid] int,
[uid] int,
[rating] tinyint
)
```

I want to get to 20 messages from messages table with the sum of the ratings for each message and the count of ratings for each message.

```
select 
    msg.id, msg.text,
    sum(rate.rating), 
    count(rate.id) 
from 
    messages as msg 
inner join 
    ratings as rate on msg.id = rate.msgid 
group by 
    msg.id
```

can any one please help me with the SQL query code?

Comment: Show us the effort you've already put into solving this - explain where you're stuck, and we'll be glad to help. But we don't just write the code for you ....

Comment: I edited my question and added the code I have tried

Comment: And what's the problem with your code? Do you get an error - if so: **what** error? Does it not return the data expected - then what **did** you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select columns which haven't been used in `group by` clause.

Try:

```
select 
    msg.id, msg.text,
    sum(rate.rating), 
    count(rate.id) 
from 
    messages as msg 
inner join 
    ratings as rate on msg.id = rate.msgid 
group by 
    msg.id, msg.text
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to coordinate the `group by` with the `select`.  Also, account for zero ratings, so use a left join:

```
SELECT
    msg.id,
    msg.text,
    SUM (COALESCE (rate.rating, 0) )   AS ratingSum,
    COUNT (COALESCE (rate.id, 0) )     AS ratingCnt
FROM
    messages as msg
LEFT JOIN
    ratings rate ON msg.id = rate.msgid
GROUP BY
    msg.id,
    msg.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
select msgid,
count(msgid) MsgCount,
       sum(rating)  RatingSum
from ratings
where msgid = [some msgid]
group by msgid, rating
```

This should work on most ANSI standard transact sql platforms. You may have to modify it for your particular database.

Thanks,
--James Walsh Jr.
--Developer at Large

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!